# Open source OBD II scanner hardware without ELM or STN

Tags: troubleshooting, obd-ii, electronics, scan-tool

We have built an OBD-II scan tool using an STM32 microcontroller and it works for most vehicles. But occasionally our device fails to detect the OBD protocol, whereas the OBD scanner (ELM) will detect it. We are following international standard documentation provided by ISO and so the logic is theoretically correct, also this setup works for most vehicles.

Are there any open source implementations of an OBD scanner using a microcontroller instead of ICs/firmware like ELM327? Basically, I need to know how an OBD II scanner sends its frames into the CAN/K-Line bus.

Comment: You are aware there are vehicles out there which have the ECUs on either the L-Line (Audi was a prominent example) or a secondary CAN? So it may be just a matter of wiring.

Comment: Your best bet may be to reverse engineer what you have. Probe the lines and record what happens during the detection process. Then compare this to a recording of how your scanner does the detection.

Comment: What transceivers and other hardware are you using? Is it only specific vehicles it fails to detect or is there an intermittent problem?

Comment: @Janka, yes I'm aware of that. But if the scanner can detect it then my hardware must also detect it. Unless the scanner changes it's pin configuration. The OBD connector, to my knowledge, is a standard. So I'm not sure why my setup fails even though the scanner detects it.

Comment: @vini_i Thank you, I'm currently doing that. It's a bit hard as I don't own a scope, so currently using a LabJack U3.

Comment: @Terry Gould, I'm using a STM32F103, MSP2515 for CAN and SN65HVDA100 for KWP. CAN detection and PID request are smooth for most cars (except we had a CAN tx fail for an Audi Q5) and ISO9141 and ISO 14230-slow are also good. Except for ISO 14230-fast (KWP FAST). Which is failing for most kwp fast cars.

Comment: A CAN bus sniffer may do you better justice than a scope or LabJack. Also are you sure that the cars that your failing to connect to have CAN. In the US CAN was not mandatory until 2008. This leaves a 12 year gap of vehicles that could possibly use something other than CAN (Class 2 or LIN for example).

Comment: So the problem is only with KWP fast? - You may want to move the question over to EE.SE.

Comment: @JimmyB, yes I'm only facing a problem with KWP fast. I have solved the issue. Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an open source scanner firmware, but we have solved the KWP issue that we were facing. Still open for any mention on open source OBD II scanners.

I use the same GPIO pin as both GPIO and UART TX, which is what we must do. But when switching between that two modes the pin goes into ***high impedance*** mode and so there was a drop in voltage which the KWP ECU will see/read.Thus there was a faulty bit in the bus, and so obviously the "handshake" failed. We have fixed this with a pull-up resistor.